# The multi-part identifier could not be bound update column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE country
SET country.postcode = (SELECT t.postcode
                        FROM Patch_Country t
                        WHERE t.Rows = 2 AND tll.id = t.id),
    country.state = (SELECT t.state
                     FROM Patch_Country t
                     WHERE t.Rows = 1 AND tll.id = t.id)
FROM country tla WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN country2 tll ON tla.id = tll.id
WHERE tll.code = tla.code
```

I tried to add inner join at the rows still showing error I'm not sure why this error is showing.

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Comment: Here your query return `SELECT t.postcode
                FROM Patch_Country t
                WHERE t.Rows = 2
                    AND tll.id= t.id` multiple rows first you check or go with 1 row per result set.

Comment: Stop splattering table hints in your code if you do not understand what they do, do not undrstand what problems they can cause, and do not have any defined purpose.

Comment: @ethan . . . There is nothing *a priori* wrong with your query (although it definitely has room for improvement).  If an identifier cannot be bound, it is because a column does not exist in the referenced table, and your question has not provided enough information to address that.  Sample data and desired results almost always make a question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
UPDATE country
SET country.postcode = (CASE WHEN t.Rows = 2 THEN t.postcode END),
    country.state = (CASE WHEN t.Rows = 1 THEN t.state END)
FROM country tla 
INNER JOIN country2 tll ON tla.id = tll.id AND tll.code = tla.code
INNER JOIN Patch_Country t ON tll.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues of this error is , you have used your table abbreviations incorrectly

try below code

`UPDATE country
SET postcode = (SELECT t.postcode
                        FROM Patch_Country t
                        WHERE t.Rows = 2 AND tll.id = t.id),
    state = (SELECT t.state
                     FROM Patch_Country t
                     WHERE t.Rows = 1 AND tll.id = t.id)
FROM country tla WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN country2 tll ON tla.id = tll.id
WHERE tll.code = tla.code`

Comment: the error will prompt with the select statement. tll.id count not be bound